# How to substring of a string with dynamically changing long text where indexes are unknown

Tags: java

I have a text as below

```
String text= new String("Java is a general-purpose computer-programming language that is concurrent, class-based, object-oriented,and specifically designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible. It is intended to let application developers "write once, run anywhere" (WORA),[16] meaning that compiled Java code can run on all platforms that support Java without the need for recompilation. Java applications are typically compiled to bytecode that can run on any Java virtual machine (JVM) regardless of computer architecture. As of 2016, Java is one of the most popular programming languages in use, particularly for client-server web applications, with a reported 9 million developers.[22] Java was originally developed by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems (which has since been acquired by Oracle Corporation) and released in 1995 as a core component of Sun Microsystems' Java platform. The language derives much of its syntax from C and C++, but it has fewer low-level facilities than either of them.")
```

How can get the sub string from the above string starting from **As of 2016** part to the end. as below

```
 As of 2016, Java is one of the most popular programming languages in use, particularly for client-server web applications, with a reported 9 million developers.[22] Java was originally developed by James Gosling at Sun Microsystems (which has since been acquired by Oracle Corporation) and released in 1995 as a core component of Sun Microsystems' Java platform. The language derives much of its syntax from C and C++, but it has fewer low-level facilities than either of them.
```

Here we have substring method of a String if we know the indexes. How to get the subpart of the text when indexes are difficult to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the indexof function to get the position of you starting subString :

```
text.substring(text.indexOf("As of 2016"), text.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you just have to split your code into two steps. First you compute the indexes you want, and then you extract the substring.

How do you compute the indexes you want? Well, that depends on what indexes you want. If you want to find where the string `As of 2016` starts in the longer string, you can use the `indexOf()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through this text till you find the "As of 2016", then you know the starting index or till the end of this text